# How to hide/remove Print Page header from jquery data table print?

Tags: php, jquery

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#example').DataTable({
     dom: 'Bfrtip',          
     buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'print',
        }
    ]           

    });
  });
  </script>
```

This is  the script I have got from jquery data table documentation which is printing properly my jquery data table. Just I want to remove the header whixh is getting printed alongwith this data. How can I remove it ?

Comment: Use a `@media print` stylesheet to set the element as `display: none`

Comment: $('#results-table > thead > th').css('display','none');

Comment: I want to remove page header not table th header